# Editing challenge: making questions and answers more shareable

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat, challenge

As we approach [Winter Bash 2016](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/), let's run our eye over the site and look for questions and answers that can be freshened up, keeping in mind [What makes a question (and its answers) worth sharing?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3148/1006).

Are there places where we simply did a lookup for someone and said "Is this your person?"  Can we edit these to emphasize a "how to do it" approach instead?

For example: if the reason someone's initial search failed because their study person or place was indexed badly, can we add something about how we changed up the search parameters to find the record -- something that will help more people than just the original person asking the question.

---

If you have any ideas for future challenges, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!