# Promoting the site: sharing our questions?

Tags: discussion

This is a follow-up to [What makes a question (and its answers) worth sharing?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3148/1006).

I was reviewing all of the questions for which someone has earned the Announcer badge on the main site:

> Share a link to a question later visited by 25 unique IP addresses. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer

The badge has only been awarded 12 times and to a handful of users.

Let's take a look at the questions which drew those visits (that is, after being shared, they actually attracted people to come take a look).

- [How to access digitised content at a FamilySearch Affiliate Library?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/13438/1006) asked Oct 8, 2017
- [Catch 22: how do you know if a data provider's sub will be valuable to you — before you subscribe?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/6696/1006) asked Dec 6, 2014
- [What tools exist for collecting and managing evidence?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/177/1006) asked Oct 10, 2012
- [Are there checklists or templates made for visiting the Family History Library in Salt Lake City?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3289/1006) asked Mar 21, 2013
- [What "hidden" clues are there in the GRO Indexes of births and deaths?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/10355/1006) asked Feb 14, 2016
- [Was the 1939 Register really updated after the end of National Registration?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9875/1006) asked Oct 28, 2015
- [How should I record women with unknown maiden name?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/127/1006) asked Oct 10 2012
- [Organising digital documents for genealogy and family history?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2945/1006) asked Jan 8 2013
- [Finding half-sister who may still be living?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3507/1006) asked Jun 20, 2013
- [Can anyone decipher the comment above Louis' name on this 1940 census record?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2470/1006) asked Dec 4, 2012
- [How many genealogists and users of genealogy programs?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1954/1006) asked Nov 5, 2012

Looking at this list, I see a couple of interesting things.

- Many of these questions are basic research questions, rather than specific "I can't find my family" questions.
- Most badges were awarded (with one exception) either to the person who asked the question, or to someone who had written an answer to it.

That makes me wonder:
 - When you ask a question, do you share it, and where?
 - When you answer a question, do you share it, and where?
 - Do you share someone else's Q/A, and if so, where?

Note that the site has been going four years now, and NO ONE has earned:

> Booster - Share a link to a question later visited by 300 unique IP addresses

or

> Publicist - Share a link to a question later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses

Why aren't we tooting our own horn more?  How can we make our questions worth looking at and worth being shared?

Answer (score 1):

I share questions/answers from here when I see similar questions asked in other fora, in the hope that getting a good answer to an immediate question will encourage somebody to come back here.

I don't tweet or blog about questions or share them in other social media -- my 'reach' is insufficient for it to be worthwhile and I'm not totally convinced that somebody will follow a link unless it's immediately relevant to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are right to highlight the **share** button beneath every post.

Although I have the Announcer badge 8 times on GIS (0 for Booster and Publicist) I have not received it here.

I think that is because my Twitter followers have been cultivated around my profession (GIS) rather than my hobby (G&FH).  I am keen not to "dilute" my GIS content too much and so I rarely share G&FH posts.

Something that I am considering is to create a second Twitter handle targeted at a G&FH following.

Comment: I have two twitter handles -- one for my writing career and one for Family History, specifically to separate the two audiences.  Not that many people follow either of them :)

Comment: I don't have a big following either, but I am sharing Harry's GRO index hack along with the news item about the GRO PDF Pilot, hoping to get people's interest.

Comment: I also have more than one Twitter handle -- my genealogy handle is tightly curated.